# What is the difference between Android Studio Beta Channel, Android Studio Canary Channel, Android Studio Dev Channel?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android and wondering what studio to install and what is the difference between Android Studio Beta Channel, Android Studio Canary Channel, Android Studio Dev Channel?

[image]

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Canary channel**: Canary builds are the bleeding edge, released about weekly. While these builds do get tested, they are still subject to bugs, as we want people to see what's new as soon as possible. This is not recommended for production.

**Dev channel**: Dev builds are hand-picked older canary builds that survived the test of time. It should be updated roughly bi-weekly or monthly.

**Beta channel**: This is used for beta-quality releases.

**Stable channel**: This is used for stable releases, which are considered suitable for production.

Comment: If it is correct, please mark that answer as solution - an upvote would also be nice

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated! I believe that they have now rolled out even the stable channel, implying that android studio is no longer in the preview stage

Comment: and, i think, the beta channel is also used now

Comment: @AndroidMechanic you can never use beta for production

Comment: @reubenjohn please read the answer again