# Android Studio 3.1 Canary 4 Genymotion Emulator Plugin Failed

Tags: android, android-emulator, kotlin, genymotion, android-virtual-device

I'm using **Android Studio 3.1 Canary 4** with **Kotlin Support**. Since the default **Android AVD** is too slow, I prefer **Genymotion**. Inspite of installing Necessary Plugins, there is no option for Genymotion Emulator in the Android Studio.Is it not supported being Beta? Or am I missing something ?

[Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtMIE.png)

[Installed Genymotion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzwDM.png)

**PS** : [Installed Virtual Box,Genymotion, Android Studio] And Selected SDK from Genymotion. Also Configured the virtual box. And Restarted a lot of times after doing each steps

Answer (score 0):

Please use stable Channel of Android Studio for full flexed functionality 
Try to update your android studio to 3.0.1 version and it will work [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418487/what-is-the-difference-between-android-studio-beta-channel-android-studio-canar/26418512)

for updating Android studio go to Help>Check For Updates> Updates> Stable Channel
[image]